# Passing json text to aws cli container

Tags: json, bash, shell, docker, aws-cli

I have a json file which i am processing like this.

```
aws application-autoscaling put-scaling-policy \
        --service-namespace dynamodb \
        --resource-id "table/$DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME_PREFIX$tablename" \
        --scalable-dimension "dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits" \
        --policy-name "WriteScalingPolicy" \
        --policy-type "TargetTrackingScaling" \
        --target-tracking-scaling-policy-configuration \
        '{
        "PredefinedMetricSpecification": {
            "PredefinedMetricType": "DynamoDBWriteCapacityUtilization"
        },
        "ScaleOutCooldown": 60,
        "ScaleInCooldown": 60,
        "TargetValue": 80.0
        }'
```

Please note that `aws` is a function here, which we are using like this.

```
aws() {

  docker exec aws-cli aws $*
}
```

aws-cli container is an already running container and command from `application-autoscaling` to json text is passed to awscli container like this.

```
docker exec irtci-awscli aws application-autoscaling put-scaling-policy --service-namespace dynamodb --resource-id table/ir-tci_app_resource --scalable-dimension dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits --policy-name ReadScalingPolicy --policy-type TargetTrackingScaling --target-tracking-scaling-policy-configuration '{' PredefinedMetricSpecification: '{' PredefinedMetricType: DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization '},' ScaleOutCooldown: 60, ScaleInCooldown: 60, TargetValue: 80.0 '}'
```

which is not parsed by the awscli container because of IFS, i believe.
I am getting following error.

```
`Unknown options: --target-tracking-scaling-policy-configuration, PredefinedMetricSpecification:, {, PredefinedMetricType:, DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization, },, ScaleOutCooldown:, 60,, ScaleInCooldown:, 60,, TargetValue:, 80.0, }, {
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
aws() {
  docker exec aws-cli aws "$@"
}
```

[Bash Reference Manual: Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#index-_0024_002a)

> *
>   ($*) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion is not within double quotes, each positional parameter expands to a separate word. In contexts where it is performed, those words are subject to further word splitting and pathname expansion. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special variable. That is, "$*" is equivalent to "$1c$2c…", where c is the first character of the value of the IFS variable. If IFS is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces. If IFS is null, the parameters are joined without intervening separators.
>
> @
>   ($@) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" …. If the double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last part of the original word. When there are no positional parameters, "$@" and $@ expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

Comment: It's processing like this. almost correct but still throwing error.

Error is..
Unknown options: --target-tracking-scaling-policy-configuration, {
        "PredefinedMetricSpecification": {
            "PredefinedMetricType": "DynamoDBWriteCapacityUtilization"
        },
        "ScaleOutCooldown": 60,
        "ScaleInCooldown": 60,
        "TargetValue": 80.0
        }

Comment: What about if you run `docker exec aws-cli aws application-autoscaling put-scaling-policy ...` directly?

Comment: docker exec irtci-awscli aws application-autoscaling put-scaling-policy --service-namespace dynamodb --resource-id table/ir-tci_app_resource --scalable-dimension dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits --policy-name ReadScalingPolicy --policy-type TargetTrackingScaling --target-tracking-scaling-policy-configuration '{
        "PredefinedMetricSpecification": {
            "PredefinedMetricType": "DynamoDBWriteCapacityUtilization"
        },
        "ScaleOutCooldown": 60,
        "ScaleInCooldown": 60,
        "TargetValue": 80.0
        }'
still the same error

Comment: I guess the problem is in the docker image `irtci-awscli`, could you check what's the version of `aws-cli` inside? I noticed there are two different aws-cli image names. `docker exec irtci-awscli aws --version` and `docker exec aws-cli aws --version`

Comment: Yes, it was cli version incompatibility, after I updated to latest version. It worked . Thank You.